# Could not load type Readme

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was doing a project using unity and C#, all of a sudden my laptop crashed and after it restarted the project was giving me this error message:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type Readme, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute: (null)
System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) (at <3dd5df5ef4974f29afeb2d3ba227c5da>:0)
System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <3dd5df5ef4974f29afeb2d3ba227c5da>:0)
System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <3dd5df5ef4974f29afeb2d3ba227c5da>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.Rebuild () (at <8a1c902e1cc24cec8e4dda915647a0cd>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorTypeByType (System.Type type, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <8a1c902e1cc24cec8e4dda915647a0cd>:0)
UnityEditor.CustomEditorAttributes.FindCustomEditorType (UnityEngine.Object o, System.Boolean multiEdit) (at <8a1c902e1cc24cec8e4dda915647a0cd>:0)
UnityEditor.SceneView:Awake()
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:LoadSerializedFileAndForget(String)
UnityEditor.WindowLayout:LoadDefaultWindowPreferences()
```

The error just keeps repeating on and on and the project was completely fine before the laptop crashed. any solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After closing Unity, delete the Library, Logs, and obj directories and start Unity again. This is an approach I often take when I have a problem with a Unity project and can't figure out the cause.

This will rebuild the files generated by Unity. It will not affect any code or resources you have added, but if you are concerned, make a copy.

[image]